# Constrain or subtype an Unbounded_String in Ada with rules?

Tags: string, constraints, ada

new to Ada but loving it so far. I'm probably asking this question in a noob way since I'm sort of just muddling through writing something useful as my foray, but here goes:

I've got a system which uses `Unbounded_String`s and I wanted to apply some rules to them, namely things like whether the length was divisible by `n` or which characters they could contain. Is there a neat way of going about this so that I can lean on the type system for the validation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can ask the type system to check values as they are assigned to variables, with Dynamic_Predicate aspects:

```
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
package UB_Preds
is
   use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

   subtype Even_Length_String is Unbounded_String
   with Dynamic_Predicate => Length(Even_Length_String) mod 2 = 0;

   subtype Lower_Case_String is Unbounded_String
   with Dynamic_Predicate =>
      (for all C of To_String(Lower_Case_String) => C in 'a' .. 'z');

end UB_Preds;
```

Example of usage: if you compile with assertion checks enabled (-gnata for GNAT), these declarations will raise Assert_Failure because the assigned value fails the predicate of the subtype:

```
Odd : UB_Preds.Even_Length_String := To_Unbounded_String ("ABC");
UC : UB_Preds.Lower_Case_String := To_Unbounded_String ("aBc");
```

The first one has three characters, so Length mod 2 /= 0, while the second has an upper-case character.

In general, the enabling/disabling of assertion checks is controlled with pragma Assertion_Policy. The default for GNAT is to ignore assertions, but -gnata enables them.

(Of course, if you use any character set other than 7-bit ASCII, you should use Ada.Characters.Handling to test for lower/upper case, not the simple range that the example above uses.)

Comment: I've tried to enable the assertion check with `pragma Assertion_Policy(Check)` inside the package where the type is defined and inside the project to no avail.

The only way I've gotten it to work so far is by invoking gprbuild with `-gnata`. Placing `-gnata` in the Compiler.Default_Switches directive does nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update, I have also tried putting `pragma Assertion_Policy(Check);` at the top of the file that defines the package containing my custom subtype and nothing.

Comment: Hm. I did not test with the pragma, before, but I did now, and I see the same behaviour as you report. All I can say is "interesting", and something to discuss with AdaCore. I think the RM is clear on this.

Comment: I had to add the `-gnata` option to both the library's `*.gpr` and to the `*.gpr` for the project which uses the library and the pragma appeared to have no effect. Quite frustrating as it would be nice to not have to ask the user of the library to change their project configuration for this to work.